# Decodable to JSON Swift 4

Tags: json, struct, swift4, decodable

I was convert DATA to Decodable struct. Now I have to store "Decodable struct" in KeyChain. But There is no way to store decodable struct in keychain. Is there any way?

I was used
https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/securing-user-data-with-keychain-for-ios-e720e0f9a8e2 for keychain. and this for https://roadfiresoftware.com/2018/02/how-to-parse-json-with-swift-4/ Json parsing. I want to store Decodable object in Keychain.

Answer (score 1):

You can store JSON or Property List data as **secure note**.

In the query dictionary pass an appropriate string identifier as value for key `kSecAttrService` and `"secure note"` as value for key `kSecAttrDescription`.

Comment: Hi @Vadian Could please explain with demo I did not understand. I was used "pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 11.0'" for store data in key chain I want to store "Decodable struct" in this.

Comment: You didn’t mention at all in the question that you’re talking about iOS. Secure notes are not available on iOS. Maybe [this article](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/securing-user-data-with-keychain-for-ios-e720e0f9a8e2) can help you.